# sendBeacon JSON Data not getting read (serverside) Nodejs and JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, sendbeacon

I am trying to send a POST request on visibility change (as described in the docs) and am having limited success. I make the sendBeacon request successfully, but cannot seem to read the object on my Node.js Express server. Here is my Send Beacon js code:

```js
navigator.sendBeacon("/delete-room", JSON.stringify({roomID: 'test'}))
```

Then, when I handle it through express:

```js
app.post('/delete-room', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('Recieved ' + req.body)
    res.status(200).end()
})
```

I get this log: `Recieved [object Object]`.
I can't read `req.body.roomID`, even after parsing the body (which returns the error cannot parse [object Object]). I also tried encoding it in a form:

```js
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append('roomID', 'test')
            
navigator.sendBeacon("/delete-room", data);
```

Which returns this log on the server: `Recieved {}`.

Why can't I receive this request? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code

```
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append('roomID', 'test')       
navigator.sendBeacon("/delete-room", data);
```

the `sendBeacon()` function send data in a raw format via HTTP POST request.

Install **body-parser** express middleware (`npm install body-parser --save`) then:

```
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.raw());

app.post('/delete-room', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('Received ' + req.body)
    res.status(200).end()
})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Started server at http://localhost:8080!`));
```

Comment: Could I use this with JSON bodyparser (what I am already using)?

Comment: Sure! Just add `app.use(bodyParser.json());`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Would it work if I also did `app.use(bodyParser.raw());` (and `app.use(bodyParser.json())`)?