# Parse sendBeacon data in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sendbeacon

I'm trying to start logging my own [WebVitals](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals#load-web-vitals-from-a-cdn). The simple use-case in their example docs looks like this:

```
function sendToAnalytics(metric) {
  // Replace with whatever serialization method you prefer.
  // Note: JSON.stringify will likely include more data than you need.
  const body = JSON.stringify(metric);

  // Use `navigator.sendBeacon()` if available, falling back to `fetch()`.
  (navigator.sendBeacon && navigator.sendBeacon('/analytics', body)) ||
      fetch('/analytics', {body, method: 'POST', keepalive: true});
}
```

That all seems simple enough. Here's my actual implementation:

```
function sendToLog(metric) {
    // Replace with whatever serialization method you prefer.
    // Note: JSON.stringify will likely include more data than you need.
    const body = JSON.stringify(metric);
    console.log(`Sending body ${body}`);
  
    // Use `navigator.sendBeacon()` if available, falling back to `fetch()`.
    // (navigator.sendBeacon && navigator.sendBeacon('https://localho  st:9292/api/log', body)) ||
        fetch('https://localhost:9292/api/log', {body: body,   method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, keepalive: true});
}
```

I had to modify the `fetch` to include the `"body"` property name and add `headers` to get it to work, but that is now working. However, if I uncomment the `navigator.sendBeacon` line, I just get `{}` for the body.

I'm using NodeJS and Express on the backend. My starting point was this:

```
const app = express();
app.use(
    express.json({
        // We need the raw body to verify webhook signatures.
        // Let's compute it only when hitting the Stripe webhook endpoint.
        verify: function (req, res, buf) {
            if (req.originalUrl.startsWith(API_PREFIX + '/webhook')) {
            req.rawBody = buf.toString();
            }
        },
    })
);
app.use(cors());

// Expose an endpoint for client logging.
app.post(API_PREFIX + '/log', async (req, res) => {
  const message = req.body;

  console.log('Got message');
  console.dir(message, { depth: null });
  logger.info(message);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

There's [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746784/sendbeacon-json-data-not-getting-read-serverside-nodejs-and-js/65747133#65747133), where the accepted answer suggests that adding `body-parser` and `app.use(bodyParser.raw())` should do the trick, and then in the comments there's discussion of using `bodyParser.json())` instead.

I've tried both of those:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
...
//app.use(bodyParser.raw());
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    express.json({
        // We need the raw body to verify webhook signatures.
        // Let's compute it only when hitting the Stripe webhook endpoint.
        verify: function (req, res, buf) {
            if (req.originalUrl.startsWith(API_PREFIX + '/webhook')) {
            req.rawBody = buf.toString();
            }
        },
    })
);
app.use(cors());
```

(i.e., uncommenting either of the two lines at the beginning), and in all 3 cases I still get an empty body when `sendBeacon` is used.

The [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) says,

> [`express.json`] is a built-in middleware function in Express. It
> parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on
> body-parser....A new body object containing the parsed data is
> populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body),
> or an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the
> Content-Type was not matched, or an error occurred.

So, a) I guess I shouldn't need the `body-parser`, since `express.json` is just doing that anyhow; and b) I'm hitting one of those three conditions (there's no body to parse, the Content-Type was not matched, or an error occurred). Assuming that's the case, how do I diagnose which one it is, and then fix it (in such a way that the `fetch` fallback continues to work). Or, if there's some other problem, back to the original question, how do I get this to work? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) sends `Content-Type: text/plain` whereas [`express.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) only parses the body if `Content-Type: application/json`.

Use [`express.text()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.text) in combination with `JSON.parse(req.body)` instead, or additionally:

```js
app.post(API_PREFIX + '/log',
  express.json(), express.text(), function(req, res) {
  if (typeof req.body === "string") req.body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  ...
});
```